# htaccess url rewriting to sub directory without changing the addressbar

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello I would like to achieve the following, but i'm not sure if it's possible with .htaccess and/or how to do so.

```
http://domain/admin/rest should go to http://domain/backend/www/rest
http://domain/rest should go to http://domain/frontend/www/rest.
```

but preferably without changing the url in the address bar.
rest can be anything like 'news/1/'.

If it's not possible in .htaccess, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/(frontend|backend) [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/?   /backend/www/$1      [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/(frontend|backend) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?        /frontend/www/$1      [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

And a third solution

```
RewriteEngine on

# rewrite all requests /admin/
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /backend/www/$1 [L]

# rewrite everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend/www/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/www/
RewriteRule ^.*$ /frontend/www/$0 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your document root, try adding these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/backend
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /backend/www/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/frontend
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/www/$1 [L]
```